# Shell: log output rewrites after every curl request in a loop

Tags: shell, loops

This code keeps writing for arr[222] only. For each call it rewrites `out.txt`. How do put every call into a single file one after another?

```
arr=(34 234 222)
for i in "${arr[@]}";do curl -d "id=$i&day=2020-04-27" https://company_api/blah... | tee out.txt;done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `...company_api/blah...| tee -a out.txt;done`